# Assigning Pens doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, pen

I am trying to create pens for use in my windows form and I am having issues with the code working properly. The pens are not painting as specified. The code snippets in question are below.

If I create the pens as follows

```
System.Drawing.Pen aPen = new Pen(Color.Firebrick, 5);
aPen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Solid;

System.Drawing.Pen bPen = new Pen(Color.Firebrick, 1);
bPen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot;
```

everything works properly. However, if I create the pens as follows

```
System.Drawing.Pen aPen = new Pen(Color.Firebrick, 5);
aPen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Solid;

System.Drawing.Pen bPen = aPen;
bPen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot;
bPen.Width = 1;
```

I end up with both pens having the same color, Firebrick, but both have the dot dash style and both are 1px in width which is not what was specified. Can anyone please explain what is wrong with the code that does not work? Thank you. Clearly there is something I am failing to understand about pens.

Comment: Since you've put "System.Drawing.Pen bPen = aPen" both bPen and aPen references point to the same object (Pen)

Comment: I think I understand. So you are saying that I am NOT creating a new pen with the same properties but rather referencing the same pen. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, with the line "System.Drawing.Pen bPen = aPen" you've just set bPen being equal to aPen, you didn't create a new instance of  Pen class

Comment: Yes. I understand. This explains the results I get perfectly. Makes sense now. Thank you. I get it. You have answered me Dmitry but I cannot mark your reply as the answer because you posted it as a comment.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko: I would like to mark your reply as the answer but I am not sure how to do it since your answer came via a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the misbehavior is in the line

```
  System.Drawing.Pen bPen = aPen;
```

This code does't create *a new* `Pen` instance, instead it *declares a new reference* to the *existing* one which is aPen, Since then there's *one instance* of Pen class and *two references* to it: `aPen` and `bPen`.

P.S. Pen is `IDisposable` so do not forget to *dispose* it in order to prevent *resource leak* (*hPen* in your case):

```
 using (System.Drawing.Pen aPen = new Pen(Color.Firebrick, 5)) {
   aPen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Solid;
   // Paint with aPen here
   ...
 }

 using (System.Drawing.Pen bPen = new Pen(Color.Firebrick, 1)) {
   bPen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot;
   // Paint with bPen here
   ...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. I was aware that I had to dispose of the pens. Thank you very much for the clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

`aPen` and `bPen` are merely alias for same thing. Pen is a reference type and when you equate, it just creates a new name for same instance.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already got an answer, its good. But just FYI, if incase you want same color of a previous pen, then you can write following code:

```
Pen2.Color = Pen1.Color;
```